# Angular animating a container while child ui-view enters/leaves

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations

I have a container (I'm using it as a modal) that is always present on the page but is shown/hidden with ng-show. I've enabled animation on that element by adding transitions, so the background of the page blurs while the container opacifies / shrinks down as if falling down onto the page from above.

Inside of this modal I have a `ui-view`. When this view is animating it's enter/leave state, the modal will not animate in. 
For instance, when I first open the modal by clicking on a button that activates it, there is no view currently specified, so the view it loads goes through its enter animation while the modal should be dropping in from above. 
However, the modal does not animate, it doesn't even get the animations applied, it just pops in, and you can see the initial view load into it with its enter animation (a simple slide in from the right, where the exiting view would slide out to the left). You can perform more actions in the modal while it is open and the views inside will slide out/in appropriately. 
Then if you close the modal, open it again through another flow, it has a new view to enter, but again the modal pops in instead of animating, while you see the view from the previous time the modal was open leave, and the new view sliding in.

The following styles are made using SASS.

Here is my animation code for the modal content (the pages in the modal that slide in and out from the sides):

```
.modal__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 82px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out;

    &.ng-enter {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);

        &-active {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        }
    }
    &.ng-leave {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

        &-active {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
        }
    }
}
```

As noted, this always works. The views are always sliding in and out appropriately. But while a view is sliding in/out, AND the modal is opening, the modal does not animate. Here is my animation code for the modal (which is always present on the page and has an `ng-show` expression):

```
.nw-modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;

    &.ng-hide-add {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;

        &.ng-hide-add-active {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) translateZ(0);
        }
    }

    &.ng-hide-remove {
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) translateZ(0);

        &.ng-hide-remove-active {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
        }
    }
 }
```

My question is, why does this happen? Is it a known issue? Is there something I'm doing wrong, or if not, is there a fix? 
Should I be using the advantage of the ng-hide-remove class and only applying leave/enter animations when that is not on the modal? So the views will only animate in/out when the modal is not in the process of being displayed?
 Or is does it have nothing to do with the animation of the views itself, but the fact that the view is having new content added and old content removed, and even without an animation the modal would still "pop" in?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you know that this is a `sass` code right?

Comment: You must have edited it before I included that it was sass, and now it's gone. I will put that back in.

Comment: Can you add a snippet/JSFiddle to exemplify your issue? I get your problem but would be better to answer you.

Comment: Unfortunately it's mildly classified so I can't just drop what I have into a jsfiddle :/ I'll try to see if I can work together a simplified jsfiddle for you, and maybe it will be answered in the meantime.